# Word Choice - "hope all is well, all things considered"

Tags: expressions, email, internet, interpersonal-relations

In email, and other written messaging is it appropriate (given the current state of the world) to open with something like "Hi XX, I hope you are doing well, all things considered."? I have noticed the urge to include the "all things considered" line more recently due to current world events and am not sure if that conveys the right sentiment I'm going for. In particular, is there a better way to express that I am not necessarily expecting someone to be in a good place, but instead that they are okay *factoring in the current circumstances*? Note that I am **not** asking the same as this question: [Hope all is good and you are doing well.’- Is it an appropriate opening line in e-mails](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209572/hope-all-is-good-and-you-are-doing-well-is-it-an-appropriate-opening-line-in).

My experience with "I hope you are well" in email has mostly been a response along the lines of "I hope you are well also", but there have been occasions where the person replies that they have in fact not been well and then go on to converse about their troubles. I am concerned that continuing to use just this greeting without acknowledging the present troubles in the world could be perceived as me being unaware of current events, or make it sound like I am using this solely as the opener of an email and am not genuinely inquiring about the recipients well-being.

Comment: To convey that you’re wishing for someone’s safety and sanity given the tough time we all are having, but are not particularly interested in the details, you could say, “I hope you’re holding up in the current situation.” This creates the understanding that neither you nor the recipient is actually ‘well’ in this difficult time, but you still wish for their fortitude.

Comment: This is simple conjunction of two extremely common formulas: _Hope all is well_, a common leadin to a complimentary close, and _all things considered_, a common contextual qualifier. No word choice is involved; it's a matter of phrasal choice, and there are two of them. Period. That's all they wrote.